# MongoDB .toArray() abnormally slow with node.js driver after adding indexes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know there are a few other SO questions on this, but none seem to really answer it.

I have a simple collection with less than 10 docs in it (for now while testing, will be as many as 100k eventually), each pretty small (according to Compass average doc size is 200B~).

Doing a simple `collection.find({}).toArray()` is sometimes taking up to 100ms! This seems absurd to me. If I run it 20 times in a row (with a pause between each one), sometimes it takes 100ms, and sometimes 1ms, and most often something in-between around 50-60 ms.

What would possibly be causing this discrepancy? It seems like if it's the same documents the time is takes the driver to convert it to a javascript object would be rather consistent. Also, why would it possibly take 100ms sometimes to convert less than 2kb of docs into javascript objects? `JSON.parse()` for example takes 0.1 ms to do the same task from a string of the same size.

I have used MongoDB is several projects in the past and don't recall ever having performance issues like this.

Is there a better way to send this data back to the client than `toArray()`. Is there something that I am missing that is hampering performance?

--EDIT--

I have 7 indexes on that collection (6 minus _id).

I created an identical collection without the indexes (except _id), and added the same number of docs to it. Running the exact same `collection.find({}).toArray()` on the index-less collection consistently takes 1ms or less! So somehow adding indexes to the collection are slowing down `toArray()` significantly.

From my understanding adding an index would increase `insert()` time, but shouldn't affect `find()`, other than improving query performance where an index is used. So why would i be seeing a drastic decrease in `find().toArray()` performance after adding some indexes?

Comment: Have you created the identical collection in the same MongoDB instance? What is the RAM size you are using? what storage engine are you using? were you running any other read queries that returned a large amount of data on a different collection?

Comment: @Mani, Yes it's in the same instance. Developing on a MacBook pro with 16GB RAM. WireTiger, latest version of MongoDB. No other operations were being performed on the DB while I did these tests.

Comment: @delashum I'm suspecting it have something to do with the environment it is deployed in. Have you tried this experiment in e.g. a standalone EC2 instance to remove the variable of background tasks, memory pressure, etc.? It will be interesting if you're seeing this in a more controlled environment.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha Okay, that's worth looking into. I don't quite believe that's it yet, because if i monitor my machines memory consumption and CPU levels while making those requests they seem pretty idle. I will spin up an instance though in the next few days and give it a test.

Comment: @delashum thanks. If you find the same behaviour in a controlled environment, please share your steps, documents, indexes, etc. so it can be reproduced.